# Equation system problem

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

In an online store 800 copies of a textbook between new and used have been sold, and a total of € 7110 has been obtained. A new copy costs € 10, while used copies are sold at a discount that can be 40% or 50% depending on the state of the copy. It has been proven that for every three new books one used has been sold.

a) Create a system of equations to find the number of new copies that have been sold.
b) Calculate how many copies were sold with a 50% discount.

Don't know for sure how to proceed completing the equation system at the moment they say "every three new books one used has been sold", how do I put if its from the 50 or 40% ones. Can someone give me a hand?

Comment: Put $N$ as the number of new books, $V$ as the number of used books at 40% discount, $W$ the used books at 50% discount. Then $3(V+W) = N$ and $800=N+V+W$...

Comment: @Joffan and you get a third equation with the price, which can then be solved

Comment: @JohnDoe Yes I left the ... on the end deliberately. Too subtle? :)